# I'm just starting to study the reaction, when working with the date, an error occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datepicker

react Errors occur in datepicker

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Dayjs | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Moment | null'. Type 'Dayjs' is missing the following properties from type 'Moment': calendar, local, isLocal, utc, and 50 more.

here is the source code

```
import React, {FC, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, DatePicker, Form, Input, Row, Select} from "antd";
import {rules} from "../utils/rules";
import FormItem from "antd/es/form/FormItem";
import {IUser} from "../models/IUsers";
import {IEvent} from "../models/IEvent";
import moment from "moment/moment";
import {formatDate} from "../utils/date";



interface EventFormProps {
    guests: IUser[]
}

const EventForm: FC<EventFormProps> = (props) => {
    const [event, setEvent]= useState<IEvent>({
        author: '',
        date: '',
        description: '',
        guest: ''
    } as IEvent);

    const selectDate = (date: moment.Moment | null) => {
        if (date) {
            setEvent({...event, date: formatDate(date.toDate())})
        }
    }
        const submitForm = () => {
        console.log(event)
    }
    return (
        <Form onFinish={submitForm}>
            <Form.Item
                label="Описание события"
                name="description"
                rules={[rules.required()]}
            >
                <Input
                    onChange={e => setEvent({...event, description: e.target.value})}
                    value={event.description}
                />
            </Form.Item>
            <FormItem
                label="Дата события"
                name="date"
                rules={[rules.required()]}
            >
                <DatePicker
                    onChange={(date) => selectDate(date)}
            />
        </FormItem>
        ...
```

work without errors

Comment: antd DatePicker works with dayjs, not moment. See https://ant.design/components/date-picker